# java paint () auto executed?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    private Vector<String> vlist = new Vector<String> ();
    private int mouseX, mouseY;
    Canvas c = new Canvas();

    public test () {
        setSize(400,400);
        addMouseListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                    test frame = new test();
                    //frame.setBackground(Color.yellow); 
                    frame.setVisible(true);
              }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(100f, 100f, 100f, 100f);
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(circle);

    }

    public void move() {

    }

    public void drawCircle(int x, int y) {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        repaint();

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        this.mouseX=e.getX();
        this.mouseY=e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

i want to write a testing program to learn the graphic programming in java. To run the above code, the circle is automatically drawn. Why the paint() method is auto executed? I the circle to be created when i clicked the mouse.

Comment: In addition to the other more specific advice 1) don't mix Swing components (e.g. `JFrame`) with AWT (e.g. `Canvas`).  2) `setSize(400,400);` set the referred size for the custom rendering component and call `pack()` after is has been added to the frame. 3) Use an `ArrayList` rather than `Vector` if synchronization is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute to the class.

```
boolean draw;
```

Surround the code in the `paint(...)` with

```
if (draw) {
    // existing code
}
```

This will make the program draws only when `draw` is true.  Initially, it is false so it won't draw anything. The value attribute `draw` will be *true* when the mouse is clicked.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    draw = true;
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Swing paint manager calls the paint method when the JFrame is rendered. For more details on the inner workings of this, please see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/).

To improve your program, you'll want to

- Do your drawing in a JPanel or other component that inherits from JComponent.
- Do the actual painting in the JPanel's paintComponent method, not the paint method.
- Call the super.paintComponent() method first.
- If you want to paint the circle on mouse click then add an if block in the paintComponent method to only draw the circle if some class field boolean is true -- and then set it true in your MouseListener and then call repaint.
- Most importantly, read tutorials on how to do Swing graphics as much of it is somewhat counter-intuitive (as evidenced by Tom's answer in this thread).

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be overriding the paint() method of the JFrame to do custom painting.

You should override the paintComponent() method of a JPanel or JComponent and add that component to the JFrame.

Check out the Swing tutoria on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics.

Check out [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) for detailed information.