# How to stop the auto-repaint() when I resize the Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am still learning Java, if someone can help me I will be very happy!

Sorry for bad english, I am spanish!
I am making a tile game, the game uses the classic "game loop" that cap the engine at 60fps
The loop sleep and then call repaint();
This works fine! But..

The problem is that repaint event is called when the JFrame is resized or maximized!
For example when the JFrame is maximized/resized the game render at 10000fps but when they dont, the game render at the speed I set, so there is a way to disable Automatic repaint and make it work ONLY when the "component.repaint()" is called from my code?

The problem here is not the "game loop", the problem is that the repaint is called automatic when resize/maximized rendering the game at more fps!

```
public class Handling {
static private int fps=0;
static private int fpsfinal=0;
static int frames = 60;
static int frames_skip = 1000 / frames;
static long ticknext = GetTickCount();
static long ticksleep = 0;

public static void Run() {
    for(;;){
        Main.getDevice().repaint();
        fps++;
        ticknext += frames_skip;
        ticksleep = ticknext - GetTickCount();
        if(ticksleep >= 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(ticksleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static long GetTickCount(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public static int GetFPS(){
    fpsfinal=fps;
    fps=0;
    return fpsfinal-2;
}

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Game extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static boolean dir=true;

@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);        
    int layout=Main.layout;
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setFont(Resources.GetFont(0));    
    Camera.UpdateCameraAxis();
    Camera.DoCamera();
    Cursor.MouseLoop(); 
    if (layout==0){
        this.setBackground(new Color(210,247,255));
        for(int xx=Math.max( etc....
```

Comment: please add some code it is very hard to help you with only a description.

Comment: So you want to be able to resize your window without calling repaint()?

Comment: yes, That's exactly I want, I want the game to work at 60fps, but When I resize the repaint() is called making the game to run at 1000 fps for example

Comment: In which case, I must say that you are probably using the wrong language. Java does a lot of things on the back end that will not be within your control (legally) to change. I will do a little more research so I can give you a definitive answer, but my guess is, there is no way to do  what you are asking...

Comment: psyche, I may be wrong, check this question out and see if it helps -- [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074898/java-paint-auto-executed) specifically, check out the second answer. I feel that might be the one you need.

Comment: Also, the game LOGIC and game DRAWING work in the same moment, so when the JFrame isn't maximized or (resizing) the game works Perfect! but when it isnt the game draw runs faster than game logic causing flickering, I dont khown if there's a way to Override resize method to avoid it to call repaint, and thanks for the help n.n

Comment: that maybe will work, I will give a try, thanks for the help!

Comment: dont work, now the game instead of render more at high fps, just render white screen at high fps, but when the Jframe isnt resizing or maximized, all work fine :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so when the JFrame isn't maximized

I don't know why this would cause a problem since only one repaint request should be generated.

> or (resizing)

I can see this being a problem since repaint will be invoked for every pixel you resize the frame by. In this case maybe you can use:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false);
```

Now the components will validated after resizing is complete.

> this.setBackground(new Color(210,247,255));

Don't use code like the above since changing the background causes repaint() to be invoked which will invoke the paintComponent() method again. Painting methods are for painting only.

Comment: in what place I Should add this code: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false); in the start or in the repaint?

Comment: @LesterMurillo, why would you want to continually set this property?

Comment: the game logic & render works at set fps (60), the resize/maximized  call this more often causing overlap/more fps so the game graphics gets async with the logic making flickering, if u dont ask for this then I understand bad, (I am spanish)

Comment: @LesterMurillo, as I stated in my answer. A maximize will only generate a single paint request. And if you use my suggestion for for setting the dynamic layout then resizing the frame will also only generate one paint request when the mouse is released. This should not affect your game unless your painting code is changing the state of your game which is should not do. The only other suggestion I have is to take a look at [Full Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

> "How to stop the auto-repaint() when I resize the Jframe"

Short answer, you **don't** control it. Longer answer, you need to make sure you aren't doing any thing that changes the state (you are using to paint), in the `paintComponent` method. For example:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(100);
    int y = random.nextInt(100);
    int size = random.nextInt(100);
    g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
}
```

What happens here is that every times the GUI repaints, which is **not** under your control, the rectangle will resize, without you wanting it to. So if you want the rectangle to only repaint when **you** tell it to, you need to make sure you only manipulate the state (i.e. x, y, size) from **outside** the `paintComponent` method, and *only* use that state to paint. Something like

```
Random random = new Random();
int x, y, size;
...
void reset() {
    x = random.nextInt(100);
    y = random.nextInt(100);
    size = random.nextInt(100);
}
...
Timer timer = new Timer(25, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        reset();
        repaint();
    }
}).start();
...
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that when the User resize the Jframe, the Jframe change their size but the game was almost the same(no changes) but thanks for the help, I will try to render the game to BuferredImage and the draw the image, so the game will update Only when I want c: but still thanks for the game

Comment: Ye, but I dont change state the paint method, the problem is the repaint is called outside from my control, java should have a way to disable autodraw :(

Comment: @LesterMurillo I assumed that `Camera.UpdateCameraAxis();` or this `for(int xx=Math.max(` changed some paint state. Couldn't tell without incomplete code. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Camera.UpdateCameraAxis() change the camera x and y, but When the player isnt moving there is no change but the auto-repaint is still done and the for loop is to draw the tiles, (it's like minecraft 2d/terraria game). I am considering disabling resize in my game and making it work at fixed resolution :s

Comment: @LesterMurillo Is that `x` and `y` being used in the `paintComponent` method (that we can't see)? If so, wouldn't it make more sense to call that method in the game loop, since that's where you are explicitly calling `repaint()`

Comment: I add printf(x,y,etc) to the every game loop, the game makes no updates in the paint method, but when the Jframe is maximized, the game flickers and repaint is called, but when it's isn't the printf stop so that is not the problem.

Comment: On another note, repaint calls should be made on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You can either wrap the call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or use a Swing Timer as I do in my code. For better help, post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're code is not compilable/runnable, so it is not an MCVE