# What causes the Jframe to flicker while resizing?

Tags: java, jframe

```
public class AspectRatio extends JFrame implements ComponentListener{

    public AspectRatio() {
        setSize(100, 100);
        setVisible(true);
        addComponentListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new AspectRatio();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        int i = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight());
        setSize(i, i);

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here is an example you can copy paste. Im cant speak for anyone but myself, but when i resize, the JFrame flickers wierdly. Does someone know what causing this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do jFrames use double buffering automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an auto-refresh/auto-repaint issue.  As you drag the JPane, it tries to update layout of all of its components, causing a flickering.  This discussion should have the solution: [How to stop the auto-repaint() when I resize the Jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199008/how-to-stop-the-auto-repaint-when-i-resize-the-jframe)