# JFrame with a Transparent Background Flickers when using ComponentResizer

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency, flicker

**Problem:** An undecorated `JFrame` with a transparent background flickers when using a [`ComponentResizer`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) to resize it. As seen in the below video and MCVE, the problem does not occur with an opaque background.

`ComponentResizer` (A `MouseAdapter`) works by calculating the drag distance and direction when the mouse is dragged and changes the size of its component accordingly.

The answer to [What causes the Jframe to flicker while resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29353493/4475997) links to [How to stop the auto-repaint() when I resize the Jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26199008/4475997), which says to turn of dynamic layout with [`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#setDynamicLayout(boolean)), however, this does not solve the problem as it has no effect, possibly because macOS is not a platform that allows it to be disabled.

[image: JFrame with transparent background flickers when resized]

**Question:** How can I allow *the user* to resize an undecorated `JFrame` with a transparent background without it flickering? Is `ComponentResizer` the problem?

**MCVE:** (Length due to `ComponentResizer` class)

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JFrameFlickerMCVE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false);
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            final JToggleButton backgroundButton = new JToggleButton("Break me!");
            backgroundButton.setSelected(true);
            backgroundButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                if(!backgroundButton.isSelected()) {
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    backgroundButton.setText("Fix me!");
                } else {
                    frame.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
                    backgroundButton.setText("Break me!");
                }
            });
            final JLabel label = new JLabel("Resize Here");
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundButton);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            new ComponentResizer(frame);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    /**
     *  The ComponentResizer allows you to resize a component by dragging a border
     *  of the component.
     */
    public static class ComponentResizer extends MouseAdapter
    {
        private final static Dimension MINIMUM_SIZE = new Dimension(10, 10);
        private final static Dimension MAXIMUM_SIZE =
                new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        private static Map<Integer, Integer> cursors = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        {
            cursors.put(1, Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(2, Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(4, Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(8, Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(3, Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(9, Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(6, Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR);
            cursors.put(12, Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR);
        }

        private Insets dragInsets;
        private Dimension snapSize;

        private int direction;
        protected static final int NORTH = 1;
        protected static final int WEST = 2;
        protected static final int SOUTH = 4;
        protected static final int EAST = 8;

        private Cursor sourceCursor;
        private boolean resizing;
        private Rectangle bounds;
        private Point pressed;
        private boolean autoscrolls;

        private Dimension minimumSize = MINIMUM_SIZE;
        private Dimension maximumSize = MAXIMUM_SIZE;

        /**
         *  Convenience contructor. All borders are resizable in increments of
         *  a single pixel. Components must be registered separately.
         */
        public ComponentResizer()
        {
            this(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), new Dimension(1, 1));
        }

        /**
         *  Convenience contructor. All borders are resizable in increments of
         *  a single pixel. Components can be registered when the class is created
         *  or they can be registered separately afterwards.
         *
         *  @param components components to be automatically registered
         */
        public ComponentResizer(Component... components)
        {
            this(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), new Dimension(1, 1), components);
        }

        /**
         *  Convenience contructor. Eligible borders are resisable in increments of
         *  a single pixel. Components can be registered when the class is created
         *  or they can be registered separately afterwards.
         *
         *  @param dragInsets Insets specifying which borders are eligible to be
         *                    resized.
         *  @param components components to be automatically registered
         */
        public ComponentResizer(Insets dragInsets, Component... components)
        {
            this(dragInsets, new Dimension(1, 1), components);
        }

        /**
         *  Create a ComponentResizer.
         *
         *  @param dragInsets Insets specifying which borders are eligible to be
         *                    resized.
         *  @param snapSize Specify the dimension to which the border will snap to
         *                  when being dragged. Snapping occurs at the halfway mark.
         *  @param components components to be automatically registered
         */
        public ComponentResizer(Insets dragInsets, Dimension snapSize, Component... components)
        {
            setDragInsets( dragInsets );
            setSnapSize( snapSize );
            registerComponent( components );
        }

        /**
         *  Get the drag insets
         *
         *  @return  the drag insets
         */
        public Insets getDragInsets()
        {
            return dragInsets;
        }

        /**
         *  Set the drag dragInsets. The insets specify an area where mouseDragged
         *  events are recognized from the edge of the border inwards. A value of
         *  0 for any size will imply that the border is not resizable. Otherwise
         *  the appropriate drag cursor will appear when the mouse is inside the
         *  resizable border area.
         *
         *  @param  dragInsets Insets to control which borders are resizeable.
         */
        public void setDragInsets(Insets dragInsets)
        {
            validateMinimumAndInsets(minimumSize, dragInsets);

            this.dragInsets = dragInsets;
        }

        /**
         *  Get the components maximum size.
         *
         *  @return the maximum size
         */
        public Dimension getMaximumSize()
        {
            return maximumSize;
        }

        /**
         *  Specify the maximum size for the component. The component will still
         *  be constrained by the size of its parent.
         *
         *  @param maximumSize the maximum size for a component.
         */
        public void setMaximumSize(Dimension maximumSize)
        {
            this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
        }

        /**
         *  Get the components minimum size.
         *
         *  @return the minimum size
         */
        public Dimension getMinimumSize()
        {
            return minimumSize;
        }

        /**
         *  Specify the minimum size for the component. The minimum size is
         *  constrained by the drag insets.
         *
         *  @param minimumSize the minimum size for a component.
         */
        public void setMinimumSize(Dimension minimumSize)
        {
            validateMinimumAndInsets(minimumSize, dragInsets);

            this.minimumSize = minimumSize;
        }

        /**
         *  Remove listeners from the specified component
         *
         *  @param component  the component the listeners are removed from
         */
        public void deregisterComponent(Component... components)
        {
            for (Component component : components)
            {
                component.removeMouseListener( this );
                component.removeMouseMotionListener( this );
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Add the required listeners to the specified component
         *
         *  @param component  the component the listeners are added to
         */
        public void registerComponent(Component... components)
        {
            for (Component component : components)
            {
                component.addMouseListener( this );
                component.addMouseMotionListener( this );
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Get the snap size.
         *
         *  @return the snap size.
         */
        public Dimension getSnapSize()
        {
            return snapSize;
        }

        /**
         *  Control how many pixels a border must be dragged before the size of
         *  the component is changed. The border will snap to the size once
         *  dragging has passed the halfway mark.
         *
         *  @param snapSize Dimension object allows you to separately spcify a
         *                  horizontal and vertical snap size.
         */
        public void setSnapSize(Dimension snapSize)
        {
            this.snapSize = snapSize;
        }

        /**
         *  When the components minimum size is less than the drag insets then
         *  we can't determine which border should be resized so we need to
         *  prevent this from happening.
         */
        private void validateMinimumAndInsets(Dimension minimum, Insets drag)
        {
            int minimumWidth = drag.left + drag.right;
            int minimumHeight = drag.top + drag.bottom;

            if (minimum.width  < minimumWidth
                    ||  minimum.height < minimumHeight)
            {
                String message = "Minimum size cannot be less than drag insets";
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( message );
            }
        }

        /**
         */
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Component source = e.getComponent();
            Point location = e.getPoint();
            direction = 0;

            if (location.x < dragInsets.left)
                direction += WEST;

            if (location.x > source.getWidth() - dragInsets.right - 1)
                direction += EAST;

            if (location.y < dragInsets.top)
                direction += NORTH;

            if (location.y > source.getHeight() - dragInsets.bottom - 1)
                direction += SOUTH;

            //  Mouse is no longer over a resizable border

            if (direction == 0)
            {
                source.setCursor( sourceCursor );
            }
            else  // use the appropriate resizable cursor
            {
                int cursorType = cursors.get( direction );
                Cursor cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor( cursorType );
                source.setCursor( cursor );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (! resizing)
            {
                Component source = e.getComponent();
                sourceCursor = source.getCursor();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (! resizing)
            {
                Component source = e.getComponent();
                source.setCursor( sourceCursor );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            //  The mouseMoved event continually updates this variable

            if (direction == 0) return;

            //  Setup for resizing. All future dragging calculations are done based
            //  on the original bounds of the component and mouse pressed location.

            resizing = true;

            Component source = e.getComponent();
            pressed = e.getPoint();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(pressed, source);
            bounds = source.getBounds();

            //  Making sure autoscrolls is false will allow for smoother resizing
            //  of components

            if (source instanceof JComponent)
            {
                JComponent jc = (JComponent)source;
                autoscrolls = jc.getAutoscrolls();
                jc.setAutoscrolls( false );
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Restore the original state of the Component
         */
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            resizing = false;

            Component source = e.getComponent();
            source.setCursor( sourceCursor );

            if (source instanceof JComponent)
            {
                ((JComponent)source).setAutoscrolls( autoscrolls );
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Resize the component ensuring location and size is within the bounds
         *  of the parent container and that the size is within the minimum and
         *  maximum constraints.
         *
         *  All calculations are done using the bounds of the component when the
         *  resizing started.
         */
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (resizing == false) return;

            Component source = e.getComponent();
            Point dragged = e.getPoint();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(dragged, source);

            changeBounds(source, direction, bounds, pressed, dragged);
        }

        protected void changeBounds(Component source, int direction, Rectangle bounds, Point pressed, Point current)
        {
            //  Start with original locaton and size

            int x = bounds.x;
            int y = bounds.y;
            int width = bounds.width;
            int height = bounds.height;

            //  Resizing the West or North border affects the size and location

            if (WEST == (direction & WEST))
            {
                int drag = getDragDistance(pressed.x, current.x, snapSize.width);
                int maximum = Math.min(width + x, maximumSize.width);
                drag = getDragBounded(drag, snapSize.width, width, minimumSize.width, maximum);

                x -= drag;
                width += drag;
            }

            if (NORTH == (direction & NORTH))
            {
                int drag = getDragDistance(pressed.y, current.y, snapSize.height);
                int maximum = Math.min(height + y, maximumSize.height);
                drag = getDragBounded(drag, snapSize.height, height, minimumSize.height, maximum);

                y -= drag;
                height += drag;
            }

            //  Resizing the East or South border only affects the size

            if (EAST == (direction & EAST))
            {
                int drag = getDragDistance(current.x, pressed.x, snapSize.width);
                Dimension boundingSize = getBoundingSize( source );
                int maximum = Math.min(boundingSize.width - x, maximumSize.width);
                drag = getDragBounded(drag, snapSize.width, width, minimumSize.width, maximum);
                width += drag;
            }

            if (SOUTH == (direction & SOUTH))
            {
                int drag = getDragDistance(current.y, pressed.y, snapSize.height);
                Dimension boundingSize = getBoundingSize( source );
                int maximum = Math.min(boundingSize.height - y, maximumSize.height);
                drag = getDragBounded(drag, snapSize.height, height, minimumSize.height, maximum);
                height += drag;
            }

            source.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            source.validate();
        }

        /*
         *  Determine how far the mouse has moved from where dragging started
         */
        private int getDragDistance(int larger, int smaller, int snapSize)
        {
            int halfway = snapSize / 2;
            int drag = larger - smaller;
            drag += (drag < 0) ? -halfway : halfway;
            drag = (drag / snapSize) * snapSize;

            return drag;
        }

        /*
         *  Adjust the drag value to be within the minimum and maximum range.
         */
        private int getDragBounded(int drag, int snapSize, int dimension, int minimum, int maximum)
        {
            while (dimension + drag < minimum)
                drag += snapSize;

            while (dimension + drag > maximum)
                drag -= snapSize;


            return drag;
        }

        /*
         *  Keep the size of the component within the bounds of its parent.
         */
        private Dimension getBoundingSize(Component source)
        {
            if (source instanceof Window)
            {
                GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
                return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
            }
            else
            {
                return source.getParent().getSize();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, has a solution been found?

Comment: @CodingMason No, I probably encountered this issue during an now-abandoned hobby project years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a solution but no one was working...
The reason seems to be the redrawing of all component tree during the resize user action.
As the redrawing of the resized component and of its children components is done not only after mouse released (end of the resize) but during the resize too (during mouse dragging) I tried to comment the

```
source.validate();
```

line into
*changeBounds* method (it is continuously called during dragging).
I put the line at the beginning of mouseReleased method into a if block:

```
if(resizing == true) {
        e.getComponent().validate();
}
```

It works (the flickering is almost absent).

Let me know if this solution works for you too...